# Increment value of mysql field when function executes

Tags: mysql, database, field, auto-increment

I'm creating a new table (see image below), how do I increment the numeric value in it by 1 every time a certain PHP function is executed?
What's the PHP code?

[image]

Comment: Something like `UPDATE tablename SET bookings_counter = bookings_counter+1` will usually do but the question is whether you really want to do this. See Alexandre's answer below

Comment: @Multifromeingegno what if your user deletes a booking or you need to count bookings of a certain type for your bosses report? You will be in a world of pain in a few months time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Do not do what you are trying to do. I can see here that you want to create a counter of bookings. This is an awful solution. You can obtain this information (the number of bookings) easily using a very simple SQL query.

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM counter
```

Generally speaking, statistics should not figure in your database.

If, however, you *must* go this way then you can use a regular UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE counter SET bookings_counter = bookings_counter + 1
```

However I cannot stress enough how ugly this is. It forces you to update your statistics everytime an event occurs. This will lead you to do more queries and rely on possibly erroneous data (what if an update fails and you have a non-updated statistic ?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I need to go with the second option... so, 1) what Data type should I choose? 2) how do I wrap that MySQL syntax in PHP code?

Comment: I already wrote the proper SQL query. You should use an integer. At this point, you need to have a minimum level of knowledge on the subject. If you do not know how to execute an SQL query then I suggest you look for a tutorial on the subject.